# Pick data based on a condition in a continuous aggregate with Timescale

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have the following table with Timescale:

```
ts     timestamp
value1 decimal
value2 decimal
ts_v2  timestamp
```

I want to set a continuous aggregate like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS {schemaName}.{viewName}
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
(
    SELECT
        public.time_bucket(INTERVAL '{60 second', ts) AS new_ts_bucket,
        sum(value1)                                   AS value1,
        max(value2)                                   AS value2,
        ts_v2 of the row picked as max(value2)        AS ts_v2

    FROM
        {schemaName}.{tableName}
    ORDER BY new_ts_bucket
);
```

For example, with rows:

```
xxx, 10, 20, ts_1
xxx, 20, 30, ts_2
xxx, 30, 40, ts_3 <- highest value2, so we need this timestamp as well
xxx, 40, 30, ts_4
```

the output would be:

```
xxx, 100, 40, ts_3
```

Comment: can there be multiple value2 40?

Comment: still https://stackoverflow.com/a/37646027/5193536 lateral join should work

Comment: @nbk, yes there can be. Sorry, that slipped my mind when I wrote the question. The first one (based on ts) is the one needed. The table is quite large (3 years of data sec by sec), won't the join take a lot of space?

Comment: the lateral join would as fas as picking value2 and ts in qa correlated subquery run the code and try it, everything is slow, witth the correct indexes and the table is big